# Zend AUTH disable multiple login on diff computer or browser

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

I have a concern about Zend Auth. I've searched throughout the internet, but haven't found any tutorial, article or discussion;

scenario: Login as 'ADMIN' on 'COMPUTER 01' and 'COMPUTER 02' concurrently.

I want my user login system to prevent the 'ADMIN' user from logging in on two computers at the same time. So that when a User is already logged in, the system disables login on another machine.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware this functionality is not built in to `Zend_Auth`, but you could achieve what you want by extending the `Zend_Auth_Adapter` that you are currently using and overiding the `authenticate()` method as danielrsmith suggests.

You would need to add a table to your DB that is set/unset by the login process. The problem is going to be the unset if the user does not specifically log out, but you could store a timestamp in the DB and allow the login to expire for the next login attempt.

```
My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $authResult = parent::authenticate();
        if($this->alreadyLoggedIn(){
            $authResult = new Zend_Auth_Result(
                Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_UNCATEGORIZED,
                $this->_identity,
                array('User already logged in')
            );
        } else {
            $this->setLoggedIn();
        }
        return $authResult;
    }

    private function alreadyLoggedIn()
    {
        //check db table to see if $this->_identity is already logged in
        //then return true or false as appropriate
    }
    private function setLoggedIn()
    {
        //update table in DB to reflect logged in status
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it will, hopefully, get you started in the right direction.
Also, doing it this way will, I think, avoid the need to alter the session handler in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create session table in database:

   CREATE TABLE `session` (
     `id` char(32),
     `modified` int,
     `lifetime` int,
     `data` text,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   );
2. Store session in database by Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable. Put the following code in bootstrap.php

   ```
   protected function _initDoctrineSession()
   ```

   {
       $url=constant("APPLICATION_PATH").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."configs".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."application.ini";
       $config=new Zend_Config_Ini($url,"mysql");
       $db=Zend_Db::factory($config->db);

   ```
   Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
   $config = array(
   'name'           => 'session',
   'primary'        => 'id',
   'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
   'dataColumn'     => 'data',
   'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
   );

   Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config));
   Zend_Session::start();
   ```

   }
3. When log in, save user id or user name in session:

   ```
   $logged_user = new Zend_Session_Namespace('logged_user');
   $logged_user->logged_user = $user->name;
   ```
4. Another log in deletes all expired sessions in database firstly:

   ```
   $sessionModel = new Session();
   $sessionModel->removeExpiredSessions();
   ```

5.After log in, search session table records to see if current user already logged in:

```
$sessions = $sessionModel->querySessions();
        $flag=true;
        foreach ($sessions as $session){
            if(strpos($session['data'], $user->name)>0 and strpos($session['data'],"Zend_Auth")>0
            ){
                $flag=false;
            }
        }
        if($flag == false){
            $this->_forward('index','index');
            return;
        }
```

This will work. But there is a problem, if a user closes the Web browser before log out, the user will not be able to log in again before the session expired. Anyone can help to fix the last problem?